# Webpack uses ESM part of library although it requires CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, commonjs, es6-modules

I'm currently having a weird issue:
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Agile' before initialization`,
which is probably caused by `webpack` trying to correctly transform the `ESM` part of my library into `CommonJs`. Unfortunately, it doesn't do a good job and I end up with the  error mentioned above.

My library supports both: `CommonJs` and `ESM`. *So I'm wondering why `webpack` uses the `ESM` part and transforms it into `CommonJs`, instead of directly using the `CommonJs` part of my library?!*

**Why am I so sure that it has something to do with the `ESM` to `CommonJs` transformation?**

Well, I once forced `webpack` to use the `CommonJs` part of my library by removing the `ESM` support. By doing so, I simply deleted the path to the `ESM` module in the `package.json` of my library.

```json
"module": "dist/esm/index.js"
```

After unsupporting `ESM`, webpack was forced to use the `CommonJs` part
and it works as expected, since webpack doesn't have to transform anything anymore. (see image)

`ESM` transformed to `CommonJS` [not working]
[image]

Untransformed `CommonJS` [working]
[image]

Since my library should support both: `ESM` and `CommonJS`,
simply unsupporting `ESM` is no solution.

Here is the `package.json` of my library:

```json
{
  "name": "@agile-ts/core",
  "version": "0.2.0+17b078aa",
  "author": "BennoDev",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://agile-ts.org/",
  "description": "Spacy, Simple, Scalable State Management Framework",
  "keywords": [
    // ..
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",       // <!-- CommonJs
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js", // <!-- ESM
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
   // ..
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agile-ts/utils": "^0.0.8"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@agile-ts/logger": "^0.0.8"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "@agile-ts/logger": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/agile-ts/agile.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/issues"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md",
    "CHANGELOG.md"
  ],
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

Maybe I've misconfigured something in the `package.json`
and thus webpack uses `ESM` although it requires `CommonJs`?

- Node Version: `v16.3.0`
- Github Repo: https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/tree/master/packages/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this issue by resolving all `circular dependencies` ^^

See: https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/issues/193